# how to show list of registered users to admin in asp.net mvc4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

I have created asp.net mvc4 application using razor engine, im new to this technology and trying to figure out a way to display a list of registered users to the admin after admin logs in. Membership is using system.web.providers. can anyone tell-
firstly how to create separate roles for users, admin using entity framework
secondly how to get and display the list of all registered users with different roles to the admin.

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 15):

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var ctx = new UsersContext())
    {
        return View(ctx.UserProfiles.ToList());
    }
}
```

and in the view:

```
@using MvcApplication1.Models
@model IEnumerable<UserProfile>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Users list</h2>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var user in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@user.UserId</td>
                    <td>@user.UserName</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course in order to be able to access the `/users/index` controller action you need to first have users and roles. Only a user in the Admin role will be able to invoke it.

Here's a [`tutorial`](http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/) which explains how you could use migrations in order to seed your database with some accounts.

Here's how a sample migration configuration might look like:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<UsersContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(UsersContext context)
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(
            "DefaultConnection",
            "UserProfile",
            "UserId",
            "UserName", 
            autoCreateTables: true
        );

        if (!Roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
        {
            Roles.CreateRole("Admin");
        }

        if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("john"))
        {
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("john", "secret");
        }

        if (!Roles.GetRolesForUser("john").Contains("Admin"))
        {
            Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "john" }, new[] { "Admin" });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to add @model IEnumerable<MVC1Application.Models.UserProfile> in my view to get this to work with the standard (model => model.Username).  +1 because this got me on the right track.  Not exactly sure what the difference is.  I would think if it finds UserProfile it would not need the full model plus it has the using statement.

Comment: Would suggest perhaps the following line for checking if the user contains a role...

if (!Roles.IsUserInRole("john","Admin"))