# Passing variables from controller to display in view MVC 4 Entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to display a list of all users registered to my application. I used the register page to both display all users registered and create new users from there.

I'm passing user list to my Register view like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    using (var ctx = new UsersContext())
    {
        return View(ctx.UserProfiles.ToList());
    }
}
```

I'm unable to loop through `ctx.UserProfiles.ToList()` from

```
@foreach (var user in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@user.UserId</td>
        <td>@user.UserName</td>
    </tr>
}
```

I have `@model MvcApplication1.Models.RegisterModel` on the top of my cshtml.

I'm new to this, how can I pass a userlist from my controller to view?

I refered to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706286/), which did not become help full because I'm unable to add `@using MvcApplication1.Models
@model IEnumerable<UserProfile>` to my page without compilation/parse errors.

Comment: The `@using MvcApplication1.Models @model IEnumerable<UserProfile>` is **definitely** correct approach. What errors you get?

Comment: @WiktorZychla here is my error message. it's caused by my foreach, `CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'MvcApplication1.Models.RegisterModel' because 'MvcApplication1.Models.RegisterModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, now we have a little more information, it sounds to me like you want to allow someone to register, whilst listing all `UserProfile`s.  As a view can only accept one model, you need to aggregate `RegisterModel` and your list of profiles together, and pass that instead:

```
public class UserProfilesRegisterModel
{
    public RegisterModel RegistrationInfo { get; set; }
    public List<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

Now your account controller is going to need changing:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    using (var ctx = new UsersContext())
    {
        var model = new UserProfilesRegisterModel();
        model.UserProfiles = ctx.UserProfiles.ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Now your view will look like this:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.UserProfilesRegisterModel

// rest of view

@foreach (var user in Model.UserProfiles)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@user.UserId</td>
        <td>@user.UserName</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Note that you'll need to change the parts of your view which access properties on `RegisterModel`.  So for example:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
```

Would now become:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegistrationInfo.UserName)
```

Now that the rest is working, you'll need to make a few more changes in `AccountController`s `Register` action.  This:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
```

becomes:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(UserProfilesRegisterModel model)
```

Finally, these:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

become:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.RegistrationInfo.UserName, model.RegistrationInfo.Password);
WebSecurity.Login(model.RegistrationInfo.UserName, model.RegistrationInfo.Password);
```

Comment: Wonderful solution, any thoughts on what could be causing `ctx.UserProfiles.ToList()` to return null, I can confirm there are users in `UserProfile` table and the column names are correct.

Comment: @czl Put a breakpoint (F9) on this line: `model.UserProfiles = ctx.UserProfiles.ToList();`, step over (F10) to the next line and see if it holds any values.

Comment: Count is zero. no values are held at the moment.

Comment: @czl I just tried creating a project, using all of my code above, and it's correctly listing accounts I've created.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.UserProfile>
```

that should do the trick if I got your problem right and guessed the namespace.

Comment: I forgot to mention I require `@model MvcApplication1.Models.RegisterModel` in order for the registration form located in the same page. Since there only one model allowed, either one would result in the dis-function of user list or registration form

Comment: OK, that changes the situation a lot. I should suggest you to completely change the design :(

Comment: understand. figured it would be shady like this.

Comment: What you can do now it do define a new class that you will use as your new model. And this class will have two public properties. One _NewUser_ of `MvcApplication1.Models.UserProfile` type and another _ExistingUsers_ of type`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.UserProfile>`. Then just replace all usages od _Model_ with either _Model.NewUser_ or _Model.ExistingUser_. But you'll probably regret this later and rewrite your design anyway.